# JPQL: filter on a computed column

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm a newbie to JPA, and I'm stucking to write my query.
I need to compute and filter on a column that is not part of my entity (a status flag depending on a requested date parameter)

This is my simplified test entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable, Identifiable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "test_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "test_seq", sequenceName = "test_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime date;
}
```

And now my test queries:

```
// simple query, with my computed status => WORKS
query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e.name, e.date, "
    + " CASE WHEN :date < e.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
    + " FROM " + TestEntity.class.getName() + " e");

// simple query with ORDER clause => WORKS
query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e.name, e.date, "
    + " (CASE WHEN :date < e.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status"
    + " FROM " + TestEntity.class.getName() + " e"
    + " ORDER BY status");

// add 'where' close => KO: 'user lacks privilege or object not found: STATUS in statement'  
query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e.name, e.date, "
    + " (CASE WHEN :date < e.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status"
    + " FROM " + TestEntity.class.getName() + " e"
    + " WHERE status = 1");

// SubQuery in FROM clause => KO: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 19
query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT proj FROM "
    + "     (SELECT e.name, e.date, "
    + "     (CASE WHEN :date < e.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status"
    + "     FROM " + TestEntity.class.getName() + " e) proj"
    + " WHERE proj.status = 1");
```

If anyone can help ;)
Thanks

***update 1:***

```
// a more representative query, where status(:time) is an heavy CASE
// statement with a:time parameter and multiplle return values
"SELECT e.name, e.date, status(:time) "
    + " FROM " + TestEntity.class.getName() + " e"
    + " WHERE (SELECT status(:time) FROM TestEntity.class) IN :filtered"
    + " AND e.name IN :filteredName"
```

It's the best working solution I succeeded, but it cost a double status computing.
I found nothing better on the documentation nor google.

Comment: for 3 you only want to return something when "status" is 1, i.e `:date < e.date`, so put that as the WHERE clause! For 4, you cannot put subqueries in the FROM clause in JPQL; this is all in the JPA spec

Comment: Thnaks for the answer.

For 3, the real query is far more complicated than this one ;)
For example, the users can filter their search by none, one or multiple status.
The 'where' clause coule be: 
    WHERE status = UP_TO_DATE OR status = ABNORMAL
So I need to get the 'statys' as result

For 4: It's not possible to use subquery in JPQL, but maybe is there a way to get around ? (another way to write the query, use criteria API, .. ?)

Comment: "criteria API" simply provides the same options as JPQL string-based queries allow, so don't go about thinking it will give you more. Your example there clearly doesnt need any subquery, or you put the subquery in the WHERE clause (the normal way of rewriting queries where ppl try to put the subquery in the FROM)